# List changes even without touching it in for loop

Tags: python, list

So I'm doing day 13 of advent of code and ran into this problem and can't seem to understand what's happening.

Here's my code:

```
road = open('day13t.txt').read().strip().split('\n')

ogroad = [ list(x) for x in road ]
for i,r in enumerate(ogroad):
    for j,c in enumerate(r):
        if c == '>' or c == '<':
            ogroad[i][j] = '-'
        if c == '^' or c == 'v':
            ogroad[i][j] = '|'

rdict = {'-':'>', '\\':'v', '/':'^'}
ddict = {'|':'v', '\\':'>', '/':'<'}
ldict = {'-':'<', '\\':'^', '/':'v'}
udict = {'|':'^', '\\':'<', '/':'>'}

test = [ list(x) for x in road ]
nroad = [ list(x) for x in road ]
for i in range(3):
    for i, l in enumerate(test):
        for j, c in enumerate(l):
            if c == '>':
                ns = ogroad[i][j+1]
                nroad[i][j+1] = rdict[ns]

            if c == '<':
                ns = ogroad[i][j-1]
                nroad[i][j-1] = ldict[ns]

            if c == 'v':
                ns = ogroad[i+1][j]
                nroad[i+1][j] = ddict[ns]

            if c == '^':
                ns = ogroad[i-1][j]
                nroad[i-1][j] = udict[ns]

    test = list(nroad)
    nroad = list(ogroad)
    xroad = [ ''.join(x) for x in ogroad ]
    for l in xroad:
        print(l)
```

So these lists seem to have taken on a life of their own because in the last few lines of the outermost for loop I print out the contents of xroad which is basically ogroad. And I don't even touch ogroad at all in the for loops but it gives a different output every iteration.

Input I use:

```
/->-\        
|   |  /----\
| /-+--+-\  |
| | |  | v  |
\-+-/  \-|--/
  \------/
```

Comment: @davedwards yes that is a mistake on my end but sadly it does not change how the code works.

Comment: @menrva I think @MichaelDutscjer's answer and using `copy.deepcopy()` is the best thing to do.

Answer (score 3):

`list()` only creates a flat copy. This means lists in the list aren't copied but shared. Example in shell:

```
>>> t=[[42]]
>>> t2 = list(t)
>>> t is t2
False
>>> t[0] is t2[0]
True
>>> t2[0][0] = 43
>>> t
[[43]]
```